SSRS 2019 Connection Opening Issue
We just moved our SSRS from version 2012 to version 2019 and have been getting complaints of slow report loads. I compared report runs from 2012 and 2019 via ExecutionLog3 and noticed in the Connection Open Times field the 2012 version appeared to open the connection once or twice and then all subsequent calls were listed as 0ms ConnectionOpenTime as if the connection remained open for each call. This report seems to have a lot of calls back to its SQL Server Database. When I compare the same report called on our 2019 SSRS it looks like each ConnectionOpenTime is around 200-400ms each. It has never ran one where the ConnectionOpenTime was 0ms. There are sometimes hundreds of these calls in this report so it starts taking over a few minutes to run.
Outside of rewriting the reports to not call the database so frequently, is there a reporting service configuration that allows the connection to remain open through frequent calls back to the database? It seems to be doing this on our 2012 version but I haven't located where this would be set at?
I've checked configurations. Expecting to find a setting about keeping connection open but I haven't located one.
